# How to properly use file.json to objects on ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, hash

I'm learning and doing some exercises, but I'm stuck on this one.

```
it 'Converts a JSON to an object of type recipe' do
recipe = Recipe.from_json('data/pudim.json')

expect(recipe.class).to eq Recipe
expect(recipe.title).to eq 'Pudim'
expect(recipe.description).to eq 'O melhor pudim da sua vida!'
expect(recipe.ingredients).to eq 'Leite condensado, ovos e leite'
expect(recipe.cook_time).to eq 80
expect(recipe.featured).to eq true
end
```

It requires you to make a method so it returns the JSON file that has hashes to objects.

Currently this is what I've done:

```
class Recipe
    require 'json'
    attr_accessor :title, :description, :ingredients, :cook_time, :featured

    def initialize(arr)
        @title = arr[:title]
        @description = arr[:description]
        @ingredients = arr[:ingredients]
        @cook_time = arr[:cook_time]
        @featured = arr[:featured]
    end

    def self.from_json(path)
        arquivo = File.read(path)
        recipe = JSON.parse(arquivo)
    end
end
```

rspec says:

```
   Failure/Error: expect(recipe.class).to eq Recipe

   expected: Recipe
        got: Hash

   (compared using ==)

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
   -Recipe
   +Hash
```

I've tried many different ways to parse JSON to objects but can't do it, and the Ruby doccumentation is sort of messy.
What is wrong on my code?
Also, what is a good place to look for Ruby doccumentation besides the ruby-doc.org website?

Comment: Your class method as with any ruby method will return the last method called within in it.  `JSON.parse(arquivo)` will return a hash so your test will fail.  You need to find a way to return an instance of your Recipe class to make that test pass.

Comment: @lacostenycoder Anywhere I can look to give me more info on that? Anything ruby related for JSON is kinda messy

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def self.from_json(path)
  arquivo = File.read(path)
  Recipe.new JSON.parse(arquivo)
end
```